# how to convert YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to 2013-11-24 11:29:07 in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres char(14) fields stores datetime withou separators like 20131124112907

How to add separators so that result is string in format

2013-11-24 11:29:07

I tried Denis answer using

```
to_timestamp(timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')::text as updated_at
```

but got exception

```
  Message=ERROR: 22007: hour "15" is invalid for the 12-hour clock
  Code=22007

  File=src\backend\utils\adt\formatting.c
  Hint=Use the 24-hour clock, or give an hour between 1 and 12.
```

Comment: are you doing this conversion in sql-server ?

Comment: my server is PostgreSql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert it using `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_timestamp('20131124112907', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Comment: I tried it but got exception. It looks like this requires 12hr clock. I updated question. How to fix?

Comment: select to_timestamp('20131124154907', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');